# Make featured image background image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, background-image

On my wordpress posts I want to add the post thumbnail at the top of the page to be full width. I want it to cover the full width of the page, and when the page gets bigger the image crops or zooms in.(similar to this https://www.inthefrow.com/2016/10/3-amazing-places-eat-mykonos.html) My code below is a work in process. It works in making the picture a background image, but it is not full width. It will only be the width of the picture. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

style.php

```html
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article class="post">
    
    
        <?php $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>
<div class="banner" style="background:url(<?php echo $featuredImage; ?>) no-repeat;"></div>
    
    
    
<?php wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID()); ?>    
    <div class="post-info">    
    <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <h2 class="post-date"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', 'Location: ', ', ', ' • ' ));?><?php the_date('F m, Y'); ?></h2>

    </div>
    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <div id="wrapper-footer"><div class="post-footer"><h1 class="post-footer-comment"><?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'post-footer-comment-count', 'none'); ?></h1><div class="share"><span>share</span> <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons-post' ); ?></div></div>
        <div class="post-footer-bloglovin"><h1>never miss a post</h1><h2><a href="#">follow by email'</a></h2></div></div>
 <?php get_template_part( 'prevandnextpost' ); ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'related-posts' ); ?>

<?php comments_template(); ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile;
else :
echo '<p>No content found</p>';
endif;
get_footer();
 
?>
```

css

```html
.banner {
      max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
        height:700px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-size: cover;
```

would do

Comment: I've already included this in my css, and the images are still not full width.

Comment: Try resetting default styling using *reset.css*. 

Check out [My pen](http://codepen.io/shudhpandit/pen/XpbYyB)

Section might be inheriting margin or padding from browser's default styling.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that wordpress is retrieving full width image path. 
Post thumbnail should be full sized. 
Check the same thorugh inspect element image url 'Open in new tab'.